# SpringTemplate with Jdk 11 throws Connection reset exeception intermittently

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate, java-11

Im using Spring `RestTemplate` to make rest call to another service (NodeJS service). Intermittently getting connection reset errors. Same code was working fine with JDK 8 and Spring boot 2.0.1, after upgrading to **Amazon Corretto JDK 11 and Spring boot 2.1.5**, started seeing this issue.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1314)
```

### Suppressed Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
        ... 143 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
                at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
```

### Some blogs mentioned that JDK 11 had issue with TLS1.3

1. Tried setting up with `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`
2. Tried setting `SocketFactory` with these protocols to `RestTemplate`.
3. Tried increasing `socketTimeout` for reset client.

Still no luck.

#Code:#

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set(AUTHORIZATION, getHeader());
headers.set(OAuth2AccessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<Object> resEntity = null;
resEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange(checkTokenEndpointUrl, 
HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

**It should not throw intermittent connection reset error**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDK 11 SSL Error on valid certificate (working in previous versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016415/jdk-11-ssl-error-on-valid-certificate-working-in-previous-versions)

Comment: I am not getting ssl handshake exception. My issue is different here. It is occurring intermittently.

Answer (score 7):

We got similar issue after adding `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` in the classpath. This changed implicitly the RestTemplate request factory from `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` to `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

Specifying explicilty `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` as request factory solved the problem :

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Comment: The above solution saved my life! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

We saw a similar issue using fluent and its connection pool.

Our easiest work-around was to limit the keep-alive strategy in the connection pool to 90 seconds and the problem disappeared.  This leads me to believe that a connection that is no longer open appears open, is handed off to be used, but upon usage it no longer is open and blows up.

Obviously this cost a bit more as you increase how often you're dealing with handshake's etc, but you also decrease your connection reset issues.